Parse string with specific characters if they exist using regex
I have text containing assorted transactions that I'm trying to parse using regex.
Text looks like this:
JT Meta Platforms, Inc. - Class A
Common Stock (META) [ST]S (partial) 02/08/2024 03/05/2024 $1,001 - $15,000
F S: New
S O: Morgan Stanley - Select UMA Account # 1
JT Microsoft Corporation - Common
Stock (MSFT) [ST]S (partial) 02/08/2024 03/05/2024 $1,001 - $15,000
F S: New
S O: Morgan Stanley - Select UMA Account # 1
JT Microsoft Corporation - Common
Stock (MSFT) [OP]P 02/13/2024 03/05/2024 $500,001 -
$1,000,000
F S: New
S O: Morgan Stanley - Portfolio Management Active Assets Account
D: Call options; Strike price $170; Expires 01/17 /2025
C: Ref: 044Q34N6

I've created a regex to parse out individual transactions, denoted by combination of ticker (eg, (MSFT)), type (eg, [ST], [OP]) and amount (eg, $500,000, etc) as follows:
transactions = rx.findall(r"\([A-Z][^$]*\$[^$]*\$[,\d]+", text)

Transactions are returned as a list and look like this for example:
(META)  [ST]S (partial) 02/08/2024 03/05/2024 $1,001 - $15,000

I'd like to add logic to include description details (ie, 'D:...') if they exist.  I tried with the below pattern, but it winds up returning just one large transaction since the first two transactions don't have description details (ie, 'D:').
I'd like to see this:
(META)  [ST]S (partial) 02/08/2024 03/05/2024 $1,001 - $15,000

..
(MSFT)  [ST]S (partial) 02/08/2024 03/05/2024 $1,001 - $15,000

..
(MSFT) [OP]P 02/13/2024 03/05/2024 $500,001 -
$1,000,000
F S: New
S O: Morgan Stanley - Portfolio Management Active Assets Account
D: Call options; Strike price $170; Expires 01/17 /2025

What am I doing wrong?
rx.findall(r"\([A-Z][^$]*\$[^$]*\$[,\d]+[\s\S]*?D:(.*)", text)

Edit:
To deal with cases where colon isn't contiguous to 'D' (imperfect PDF parsing), added to @zdim's answer and this addresses the above issues:
rx.findall('\([A-Z][^$]*\$[^$]*\$[,\d]+(?:[^$]*D:?.+)?', text)


A regular expression can only match a contiguous string. So when it matches the first (META) and the D: line, it has to include everything between them.

A better method might be to create a list of lines. Then loop through the lines in reverse. When you see a D: line, keep looking until you get to the transaction line, and combine all these lines. Otherwise, when you see a transaction line, put it in the result by itself.

@Barmar, thanks for that.  The description details will only exist if the bracketed chars (eg, [ST]) match 'OP'.  Any way to use this logic to modify the above or is splitting the original text by newlines likely to be easiest

In that case, make one regexp for one-line transactions, another for the series of lines between an [OP] line and D:.  Then combine them with | to match one or the other.

Make the "rest" after the transaction part (up to and including D:... line) optional
trans = re.findall(
    r'\([A-Z] [^$]* \$[^$]*\$[,\d]+ (?: [^$]* D:.+ )?',
    text, re.X)

for t in trans:
    print(t,'\n---')

This prints
(META) [ST]S (partial) 02/08/2024 03/05/2024 $1,001 - $15,000 
---
(MSFT) [ST]S (partial) 02/08/2024 03/05/2024 $1,001 - $15,000 
---
(MSFT) [OP]P 02/13/2024 03/05/2024 $500,001 -
$1,000,000
F S: New
S O: Morgan Stanley - Portfolio Management Active Assets Account
D: Call options; Strike price $170; Expires 01/17 /2025 

Now if you need to further process that extra text it should be easy.

Awesome, thanks!  Added one element to deal with other cases where the colon isn't adjacent to 'D' (imperfect PDF parsing and all).  This gets me what I expect:  rx.findall('\([A-Z][^$]*\$[^$]*\$[,\d]+(?:[^$]*D:?.+)?', text)

Great :)  Let me know if questions/edge cases come up.  Btw, is this about the same problem as the one you asked a few days ago, to which I posted an answer?  If it is then this question clarifies that one a bit :)

@zdiim, it's related yeah.

You might use a negative lookahead, and if you only want the description you could use a second capture group in an optional part:
(\([A-Z]+\)[^$]*\$[^$]*\$[,\d]+)(?:(?:\n(?!.*\([A-Z]+\)[^$]*\$[^$]*\$[,\d]|D:).*)*\n(D:.*))?

The pattern matches:

( Capture group 1

\([A-Z]+\) Match ( 1+ chars A-Z and then )
[^$]*\$[^$]*\$[,\d]+ Match any char except $, then match $, then again any char except $ and then $ followed by 1+ times either , or a digit


) Close group 1
(?: Non capture group

(?: Non capture group

\n Match a newline
(?!.*\([A-Z]+\)[^$]*\$[^$]*\$[,\d]|D:) Negative lookahead, assert that to the right is not the initial pattern or that the line starts with D:
.* Match the whole line


)* Close the non capture group and optionally repeat
\n(D:.*) Match a newline, then capture D: and the rest of the line in group 2


)? Close the non capture group and make it optional

See a regex demo and a Python demo
If you want the whole following part until the D: part, you can change the capture group.
See another regex demo
